# How to format ng-model date inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I would like to display date in a format of 'yyyy-MM-dd' while saving the value in event.StartDate

If I remove the ng-model, it can show the correct date, which is '2017-01-26 12:00', but the value cannot be saved into event.StartDate.

However, if I add back the ng-model, the date format does not work and '/Date(1485403200000)/' is shown.

Here is my code.

```
<div ng-repeat="event in Events">    
    <input name="eventStartDate" type="text" ng-model="event.StartDate" value="{{event.StartDate.replace('/Date(','').replace(')/','') | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the date filter to `ng-model` and you don't need the `value` attribute. Try with:

```
<input name="eventStartDate" ng-model="event.StartDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" type="text"/>
```

Comment: The date format is correct now but I cannot edit the value, the error message is TypeError: u is not a function

Comment: This looks something which has nothing to do with the filter and the template...will you share some of your controller code?